# The fragment getting cut by view pagger layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

First, I want to make a tablayout fragment, and in fragment One i want to add recycler view , but the top of recyclerview getting cut by view pagger or tab layout at the top.

[getting cut at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vve9y.jpg)

The top of the recyclerview getting cut by view pagger. The toolbar is separated in other xml

this is fragmentOne.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.OneFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/navbar_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="304dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/MainRView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@layout/activity_tablayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@layout/activity_tablayout">


        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

and this is the activity_tablayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.tablayoutActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I already tried code below, or change the orientation. But its still going wrong, please someone help me

Comment: In your `activity_tablayout.xml` instead of `ConstraintLayout` just use `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation.

Comment: Thanks heisenbrg you save me

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using CoordinatorLayout with ListView. You can change your implementation to RecyclerView to achieve correct scroll.

or If you are tagetting above 5.0, you can use the following piece of code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
 listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);}
```

I think CoordinatorLayout only works with the children of NestedScrollingChild.

Comment: You are going too far from solution. By the way nice try!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the ContraintLayout with the CoordinatorLayout in your activity_tablayout.xml

[Check this out](http://www.androhub.com/android-material-design-tabs-using-tablayout/) for the source code with an example.

Also check out this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyyNxJtYTBc

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You convert your CoordinatorLayout to LinearLayout and set orientation "vertical", like this. I think this will solve your issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.tablayoutActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```